# Как удалить часть кода из файла полностью?

Tags: php, javascript

Можно ли удалить определенный `<div id="q1">` программно из кода полностью? Искал в интернете, но чего-то дельного не нашел, обычно это скрытие или удаление со страницы, но не из файла. Нужно чтобы исходный код очищался от этого `div`'а по нажатию кнопки на сайте. Любыми возможными способами.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="q1">Меня нужно удалить</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Непонятно почему "удаление со страницы" не удовлетворяет вашим требованиям..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) позволяет работать с DOM привычным нам по javascript образом:

```
// $html = file_get_contents('some.html');
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="q1">Меня нужно удалить</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$el = $dom->getElementById('q1');
$el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
// file_put_contents('some.html', $dom->saveHTML());
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/iGXKB)

Comment: А куда его добавлять? Это отдельный файл или вместо моего поставить данный код?

Comment: Куда его добавлять - это вам решать. Этот код показывает, как удалить элемент из файла `some.html`. HEREDOC-литерал и echo приведёны только для демонстрации рабочего примера в отсутствии файла

Answer (score 0):

Принципиально на JS?
Для принципиально вредных, я имею ввиду, что на сайте используются еще много возможных действий с jQuery. Не ради одного действия подключаем целый фреймворк.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="q1">Меня нужно удалить</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#q1').click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});

});
</script>

</html>
```